# RoboCopy + Atlassian Bamboo Continuous Integration

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo, robocopy

I've created a task to move my files to another server inside Bamboo using robocopy.

```
 ${bamboo.build.working.directory}\target\ \\DEVARCHER\inetpub\wwwroot\mywebsite\ /IS /MIR
```

[image]

However, when I do this robocopy returns the wrong code that is expected:

```
build   10-Jan-2014 13:41:56       Ended : Fri Jan 10 13:41:56 2014
simple  10-Jan-2014 13:41:56    Failing task since return code of 
[C:\windows\system32\robocopy C:\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\PHX-PL-JOB1\target\ \\DEVARCHER\inetpub\wwwroot\phoenix\ /IS /MIR] 
was 1 while expected 0
```

Okay so I read somewhere else to return `EXIT /B 0` but then robocopy ONLY moves folders and not files.  Anyone got any ideas why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the task to a 'script' and then inserting the following allowed my to be able to wrap the robocopy statement in params which was causing the problem.  End result:

```
 (C:\windows\system32\robocopy ${bamboo.build.working.directory}\target\ \\DEVARCHER\inetpub\wwwroot\phoenix\ /MIR) ^& IF %ERRORLEVEL% LEQ 4 exit /B 0
```

Comment: In Bamboo, this seems to be the way to do it. Tried several variants of the same thing, but this exact syntax was the only one I got working. Thanks a bunch!